# Existe opção para finalizar um tópico?

Tags: debate

Exemplo muito comum:

[Erro Undefined index: user ao enviar um formulário POST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69194/erro-undefined-index-user-ao-enviar-um-formul%C3%A1rio-post)

Esse é o clássico tópico no qual o usuário tem uma primeira dúvida que quando é resolvida, ele executa o código e cai em outro problema distinto. Obviamente ele aproveita o mesmo tópico para estender mais perguntas.

Nesses casos, não seria mais apropriado apenas um moderador ou um membro, com um certo nível de pontuação, ter permissões para encerrar o tópico a partir do primeiro momento em que o mesmo fora resolvido de acordo com a dúvida inicial, evitando assim que seja estendido "infinitamente"?

Comment: Acredito que seja o mesmo motivo da comunidade não escolher uma resposta no lugar do AP, mesmo abandonando a questão. Acho que o ideal é direcionar o AP a marcar a questão como resolvida, pontuar a resposta - se houver - e criar uma nova questão para um novo problema. *[IMHO]*

Comment: Editar questão já cria mal estar por parte dos iniciantes, imagina dar como resolvida pelo simples entendimento pessoal.

Comment: entendido!!!!!!

Comment: Boa tarde Daniel, me desculpe mas eu não consigo enxergar aonde o autor "aumentou a questão", o problema dele mesmo é que ele vem pergunta, consegue a resposta desejada e não marca nenhuma resposta como correta. Acho que ele acredita que este local é um fórum.

Comment: está no primeiro comentário que ele fez na própria pergunta. ###  "Bem deu, mas mesmo eu quando tento apagar alguém que existe base de dados, aparece a mensagem de Esse cliente nao existe –  Odacil"  ###

Comment: Tem toda razão, não me atentei ao comentário. Mas acho que o motivo realmente seja por que o AP acredita que isto é um fórum de "suporte".

Answer (score 8):

O comentário do Papa Charlie está correto.

O fato de apenas o AP poder marcar uma pergunta como resolvida é uma dos fatores mais importantes no sucesso do Stack Overflow, mesmo que acabe gerando os inevitáveis casos de abandono ou de tópico interminável.

É importante ter em mente que uma resposta no SOpt não é dada *para o autor da pergunta*. Ela é dada para dezenas, centenas ou milhares de pessoas que vão encontrar a pergunta no futuro. É importante, então, que se uma pergunta for marcada como resolvida, que a pessoa que marcou tenha plena condição de fazer esse julgamento. E isso apenas o AP pode fazer.

O sinal de resposta aceita significa que alguém que tinha o mesmo problema que você conseguiu resolvê-lo daquela maneira. Isso é muito importante. Por isso ninguém além do AP pode marcar uma pergunta como resolvida.

Comment: obrigado! está mais claro. Antes eu não sabia ao certo se esses "tópicos infinitos" eram aceitáveis.

Comment: @DanielOmine Não é que os tópicos infinitos, ou com respostas não marcadas como correta sejam "aceitos". Principalmente os tópicos infinitos, que precisam que a comunidade guie os usuários a fazer novas perguntas. Pense nessas perguntas como um "mal necessário", em troca da garantia de que só o AP pode marcar um problema como resolvido.